# Unity3D optimize code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have 2 objects that do the same thing in terms of the behavior but the only thing that differs is the damage dealt. Right now i have 2 scripts that are a copy paste from each other. Same functions same everything. How can i make 1 script to optimize my work and not duplicate my stuff? Thanks.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;


 public class Script1 : MonoBehaviour {

private float attackDamage = 5;
```

void OnCollisionEnter (Collision item)
    {
        item.gameObject.GetComponent().Damage(attackDamage);
        disableObs();
    }

```
public void disableObs()
{
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
}
```

}

Script 2 is the same thing. I just change the damage variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorate your variable with:

```
 [SerializeField] private int damage;
```

Now this is a private variable with exposure in the Inspector.

Concerning the workflow, you can drag as many of Script1 onto many objects, they will have their own Script1 set of actions. But the purpose is that you can have infantry with damage value as 1 and tank with damage as 100. All you need to do is set the value for the prefab. One place to set them all. Then you can instantiate the prefabs and they will use the given values.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the damage variable to public and when you add the script to different objects set that variable via inspector. Or if you are doing that change by code on instantiation just call the setDamage(damage) function to the specific object:

```
gameobject.GetComponent<Script1>().setDamage(damage1);
gameobject2.GetComponent<Script1>().setDamage(damage2);
```

Comment: What about my effects? Particle system same thing?

Comment: yes you can have the same scripts and particle systems in different objects with different configurations. If it was helpful please upvote as answer.

Comment: True. But i have 1 tiny problem that is not in my question. On Destroy im disabling my object, and my particle system is the child of the object. So the effect will not play because it get's disabled. is there anyway to delay the effect to be disabled? I want it to do the effect then get disabled.

Comment: Instead of Destroying it you can just disable the mesh renderer, the scripts and leaving it as if it was empty. the transform will remain but nothing will change and the particle effect will still be active. If you want the particlesystem to be destroied with delay you need to make a script for that.